# How to get the current page of Vmware clarity wizard?

Tags: vmware-clarity

We are using VMware clarity wizard to render wizard pages dynamically and we need to have custom logic to access the current page id/step id of the wizard for validation and other functionalities.

When trying to access page of the wizard, using pagesCollectionService and navService, we are getting the id's correctly for the first time e.g clr-wizard-page-0, clr-wizard-page-1 etc.
But the Problem is on click of cancel/submit from the wizard, the wizard id's are not getting reset, that is when we again open the same wizard the wizard page id's are in continuation to the previous id's
e.g :clr-wizard-page-4, clr-wizard-page-5 etc.

Is there a way by which we can access the page of the wizard by using any other property.
Note: Wizard pages are dynamically rendered using json

Attaching image : page id's that come up when we open the wizard for second time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjxkw.png)

Adding more information, 
Please find the stackblitz link for more details:
https://clarity-light-theme-v013-phyhyk.stackblitz.io

Here we are rendering wizard pages, driven by config
For every wizard page we are displaying angular dynamic forms, where config contains all the information for the form fields .
Since  is being called inside a for loop, we need to have a function where on click of next/back or on click of step of the wizard we should be able to validate the current form fields and store the current form fields value. 
I have added (clrWizardCurrentPageChanged)="resetFormValidity()" and on every page change i am trying to retrieve the page id using wizard.currentPage.id, but the id's are not getting reset and when i access the multiple times, i am getting incremental id's : clr-wizard-page-4, clr-wizard-page-5 etc.
We are using the below versions :
    "@clr/angular": "0.11.30",
    "@clr/icons": "0.11.30",
    "@clr/ui": "0.11.30",

Is there any other way where i can determine which page it is currently, so that i can compare that with config and continue with validation and form submission.

Comment: Components that can appear multiple times in a page such as `clr-wizard-page` have their ids generated by incrementing a global variable.  So the counter will keep increasing if you destroy and create new `clr-wizard-page`.  Best way is to to use `clrWizardPagePreventDefault` and handle the button clicks and performing validations as part of click of next button.   There is example of handling next button in https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/wizards

Answer (score 0):

The Wizard has a property called `currentPage` which will tell you the current page. The public methods of the Wizard are at https://v2.clarity.design/wizards under the Wizard Deep Dive section, which might replace the need to inject and use the internal services which aren't meant to be used directly in applications (from what I understood in your message, an isolated demo would help greatly).

```
@ViewChild() wizard: ClrWizard;

get currentPage() {
  return this.wizard.currentPage;
}
```